# The use of the noun "number" in context

Tags: word-choice

Tell me please if the use of the word *number* is correct and natural in the following context.

> Person 1: How many of you are today at work?
>   Person 2: We are the same **number** as we were yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Person 1: How many of you are at work today? (notice word order)

Person 2: We are the same number as yesterday. (This is correct and would be understood although it sounds like something that might have been said in the 19th century.)

Nowadays the following replies would be more likely:

Person 2:

[There's] the same number as yesterday.

[There are] as many [of us] as there were yesterday.

The bracketed parts are optional in informal speech.

Comment: +1 for pegging it as something of an archaism.

Answer (score 2):

That's grammatical but **we are the same number** is unlikely to be heard in a contemporary conversation.